# How to fuzzyjoin several dataframes in one go using IRanges

Tags: r, fuzzyjoin

I need to join several dataframes based on inexact matching, which can be achieved using the `fuzzyjoin` and the `IRanges` packages:

Data:

```
df1 <- data.frame(
  line = 1:4,
  start = c(75,100,170,240),
  end = c(100,150,190,300)
)
df2 <- data.frame(
  v2 = c("A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","F"),
  start = c(0,10,30,90,120,130,154,161,175,199,205,300),
  end = c(10,20,50,110,130,140,160,165,180,250,300,305)
)

df3 <- data.frame(
  v3 = c("a","b","c","d","e","f"),
  start = c(5,90,200,333,1000,1500),
  end = c(75,171,210,400,1001,1600)
)
```

Here I want to join `df2` and `df3` to `df1` based on the **intervals** between `start`and `end`. What I *can* do is do it in steps, i.e., join by join:

```
library(fuzzyjoin)

# install package "IRanges":
if (!requireNamespace("BiocManager", quietly = TRUE))
   install.packages("BiocManager")
 
BiocManager::install("IRanges")
library(BiocManager)

# First join:
df12 <- interval_left_join(x = df1,
                            y = df2,
                            by = c("start", "end")) %>%
  select(-c(start.y, end.y)) %>%
  rename(start = start.x, end = end.x)

# Second join:
df123 <- interval_left_join(x = df12,
                             y = df3,
                             by = c("start", "end")) %>%
  select(-c(start.y, end.y)) %>%
  rename(start = start.x, end = end.x)
```

Result:

```
df123  
  line start end v2   v3
1    1    75 100  D    a
2    1    75 100  D    b
3    2   100 150  D    b
4    2   100 150  E    b
5    2   100 150  F    b
6    3   170 190  I    b
7    4   240 300  J <NA>
8    4   240 300  K <NA>
9    4   240 300  F <NA>
```

This all works well but in my actual data I have multiple dataframes to join and, then, doing it join-by-join is impractical and error-prone. How can the join be performed for all dataframes in one go?

Comment: Related: [Simultaneously merge multiple data.frames in a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8091303/simultaneously-merge-multiple-data-frames-in-a-list)

Comment: you are not actually using IRanges in the example above. So if it is really joining like in your example, the answer below using 'Reduce' should work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put the dataframes in a list and join the dataframes with `Reduce`.

```
library(fuzzyjoin)
library(dplyr)

join_two_dataframes <- function(df1, df2) {
  interval_left_join(x = df1,
                     y = df2,
                     by = c("start", "end")) %>%
    select(-c(start.y, end.y)) %>%
    rename(start = start.x, end = end.x)
}

list_df <- list(df1, df2, df3)
Reduce(join_two_dataframes, list_df)

#  line start end v2   v3
#1    1    75 100  D    a
#2    1    75 100  D    b
#3    2   100 150  D    b
#4    2   100 150  E    b
#5    2   100 150  F    b
#6    3   170 190  I    b
#7    4   240 300  J <NA>
#8    4   240 300  K <NA>
#9    4   240 300  F <NA>
```

Comment: Super cool. What exactly does `Reduce` do?

Comment: `Reduce` will first join df1 with df2 output of which is joined with df3 and so on for all the list of dataframes present in `list_df`,